# Dynamically pass property reference from object looping key

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc, knockout-3.0

**How do I dynamically pass a property reference as a method arguments ?**

This is what ajax `success` function response data look like:

```
{
   users: {
      data: {}
   },
   countries: {
      data: {}
   },
   states: {
     data: {}
   }
}
```

This is example how i store the data previously:

```
var users = ko.observable();  
var countries = ko.observable();  
var states = ko.observable();

var store = function(data, observable)
{
    observable(data);
}

$.ajax({
   //... ajax options...

   success: function(response)
   {
       // This is how i store the data previously
       store(response.users.data, users);
       store(response.countries.data, countries);
       store(response.states.data, states);
   }
});
```

And this is example what I have try so far:

```
$.ajax({
   //... ajax options...

   success: function(response)
   {
       // This is how i want to achieve
       ko.utils.objectForEach(response, function(key, data)
       {
           store(data.data, key);
       });
   }
});
```

But unfortunately I just only pass the text string to the 2nd arguments of `store` method.

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them properties of an object, then use strings:

```
var obj = {
    users: ko.observable(),
    countries: ko.observable(),
    states: ko.observable()
};

var store = function(data, observable)
{
    var prop = obj[observable];
    if (prop) { // Just being defensive
        prop(data);
    }
};

$.ajax({
   //... ajax options...

   success: function(response)
   {
       var key;
       for (key in response) {
           store(response[key].data, key);
       }
   }
});
```